# Pandas map user-defined function with series arguments

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to create another column 'day' to save the calculation based on the country column.

I already know if i use map function it can operate on all the cells in column, but i have no idea how i can add the condition which i can make the calculation based on the corresponding country

here's an example of my data. i actually got 10 countries, and 1000 rows in my dataframe. And the real function of Us() and Hk() are way more complicated than the example one

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['Us', 'Hk'], 'Deliver': ['2', '3']})

def Us(text):
    day = int(text) +1
    return day
def Hk(text):
    day = int(text) +2
    return day

def country_in_deliever(name,text):
    if name == 'Us':
        return Us(text)
    elif name == 'Hk':
        return Hk(text)

df

  Country   Deliver
0      Us         2 
1      Hk         3
```

This is what i think. though it's wrong, the arguments i pass are a pandas series not a data of a cell.

```
df['day'] = df['Country'].map(country_in_deliever(df['Country'],df['Deliver']))
```

what i thought is i'd like to apply the country_in_deliever(name,text) on column 'Country'.

For example at index 0 when the name is 'US' the function return Us(text) which change the data type and plus 1 then save it on column 'Day'
The expected output would be like this

```
  Country   Deliver day
0      Us         2   3
1      Hk         3   5
```

Comment: Can you show your expected output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method does not use `map`, rather uses `.apply`:

```
df['day'] = df.apply(lambda x: int(x.Deliver) + 1 if x.Country == 'Us' else int(x.Deliver) + 2, axis=1)
```

```
# Result:

    Country Deliver day
0   Us  2   3
1   Hk  3   5
```

Comment: Upvote and Accept my answer if it solved your issue. (Helps the SO Community).

Comment: hi thanks for your help, though i actually got 10 countries rather than 2.. so the lumbda function would not meet my requirement.

Comment: Would be great if you could post the original df and the conditions for operations, so I can extend my answer

Comment: the dataframe is too big.. i don't know how i can put it here.

Comment: You could post a link to the DF's `.csv` file, However I believe I have answered your Question any further changes would require you to post a new question

Comment: i think you kind of distort my question. my question is to use  my self-defined function(which is way more complicated than the example one) to apply or map in the Dataframe, you instead extract the calculation out of the function and write it in one line. if i got no better solution by tomorrow i will select yours as the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

for each country add a `df.loc` line. if you want to improve that you can create a `dict` with country as a key and day_to_add as a value and make it much cleaner

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['Us', 'Hk'], 'Deliver': ['2', '3']})
df['day'] = 0
df['Deliver'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Deliver']) 
df.loc[df['Country'] == 'Us', 'day'] = df['Deliver'] + 1
df.loc[df['Country'] == 'Hk', 'day'] = df['Deliver'] + 2
..
..
```

result:

```
  Country   Deliver day
0      Us         2   3
1      Hk         3   5
```

**Edit**

with a `dict`

```
import pandas as pd
days = {'Us': 1, 'Hk': 2}

df = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['Us', 'Hk'], 'Deliver': ['2', '3']})
df['day'] = 0
df['Deliver'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Deliver'])
for country in days:
    df.loc[df['Country'] == country, 'day'] = df['Deliver'] + days.get(country)
```

now you can add to the `dict` as many counties as you wish with the same code